# Dockerise React.js craco and mongodb ELIFECYCLE

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, docker, npm

I'm trying to dockerize a reactjs-craco app with a mongo db and I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/Explorer.js:54

    for await (const place of this.config.searchPlaces) {

        ^^^^^


SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)

    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)

    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)

    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)

    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)

    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)

    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)

    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/index.js:12:17)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! my-project@0.1.0 start: `craco start`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the my-project@0.1.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-11-24T19_57_35_054Z-debug.log


> my-project@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app

> craco start
```

I've made 2 seperate folders a ui one and an api one the Dockerfile of the ui one is:

```
FROM node:8
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --silent
# Copy app source code
COPY . .

#Expose port and start application
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and the Dockerfile of the ui is:

```
FROM node:8
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# Copy app source code
COPY . .

#Expose port and start application
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

my docker-compose file is:

```
version: "2"
services:
  api:
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  ui:
    build: ./ui
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - api
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

If I run them individually the api works fine dockered with mongo and the ui runs as it should with npm start which runs craco start

Comment: Why are you using a Node 8 container? That's well out of support, you should be using 12 at absolute minimum: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.

Comment: even when i change it my docker app keeps showing that it's using docker 8

Comment: Do you mean _Node_ 8? I really doubt that if you rebuild FROM a new image you'll still see the old one.

Comment: yeah you are right I forgot to rebuilt thank you very much